# How to filter keyword search in tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I need to create a program with `tweepy` for a homework. Im not a programmer. 
I would like the program to search for menacing tweets toward for example Justin Trudeau. And then send me an email when it spot one. 
To determine if a tweet is menacing or not, the tweet would have to contain, for example, the keyword `"trudeau"` and one of the following `"bomb"` or `"kill"`. Once i get this to work, I'll refine the keyword filter.

So i have tried this:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)

searchterm1 = "trudeau"
searchterm2 = "bomb" or "kill"


search = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, 
                       q= searchterm1 and searchterm2
                       lang="en",                    
                       result_type="recent").items(10)

for item in search:
    print (item.text)
```

But it only shows me tweets with the last keyword, not one of them like it should with the or function, no?
I want to show only tweets that contain the word `"trudeau"` and one of the keyword in `searchterm2`

Thanks for your help

Comment: Comment irrelevant to your question: `Searchterm2 = "bomb" or "kill"` will always be equal to `"bomb"` and I _believe_ this is not your intention here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're gonna need [this](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators), where you'll find that your query string should be:

```py
q = 'trudeau bomb OR kill'
```

From your example you can get to that query string like this:

```py
searchterm1 = 'trudeau'
searchterm2 = 'bomb OR kill'
q = ' '.join([searchterm1, searchterm2])
```

Comment: Is there a way to exclude Tweets from users I blocked?